# como puedo hacer comparacion de texto y parrafos y javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

necesito comparar una palabra que se encuentra dentro de una variable, con el contenido de un parrafo, para poder cambiarle el color.. no tengo ni la mas palida idea de como se hace...
un ejemplo seria

```
var elemento = $('h1.ht-main-title').find('span');
var texto = $(elemento).text();
```

para obtener la palabra a comparar dentro de un div.. por ejemplo

```
<div>un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

en este caso por ejemplo si palabra que esta en la variable es Lorem, necesito pintarlo en rojo.. Alguna idea de como empezar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa `String.replace()` y una expresión regular. Para ejemplo:

```
var elemento = $('h1.ht-main-title').find('span');
var contento = $(elemento).html();
var regex = /Lorem/gi;
contento = contento.replace(regex, "<span style='color:red'>Lorem</span>")
elemento.html(contento);
```

Pero hay una problema con letras mayúsculas. Si quiere mantener la integridad de la palabra, es necesario usar $1:

`contento = contento.replace(regex, "<span style='color:red'>$1</span>")`

**Referencia:** 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace